What movie mentions that table salt is banned in the future?
I think it was a woman who said this to a man and the genre on the film was sci fi/futuristic.
I thought it was Minority Report, but can't confirm that.
Charlize Theron and Bruce Willis come to mind.
EDIT
I'm remembering a woman talking to a man in a restaurant. Maybe he was a time traveller from the past?
